# recuperar valor celda tabla con javascript

Tags: javascript

me gustaría recuperar el valor de las celdas de la primera columna de una tabla.
La tabla tiene un botón en la última columna con el que abro un modal y quiero mostrar el idCliente que corresponde a esa fila.
Estoy bastante pegado en javascript, la verdad. He probado algún ejemplo pero sólo recupero la primera fila, si pulso sobre el botón de la segunda no pinta nada.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: He intentado unos poco de ejemplos que he visto, te pongo uno para darte un ejemplo.                                                                               var t = document.getElementById("tablaCliente").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
        //t[i].onclick = getVal;
     $("#idCliente").val(t[i]);

Comment: edita tu pregunta y coloca lo que has intentado

Comment: Hola Samir, ya lo he logrado, muchísimas gracias por tu interés. La verdad que para javascript soy un negado, le seguiré dando duro.

Answer (score 0):

después de mucho intentar ya lo he logrado, estaba haciendo una función a la que con el evento click de un botón intentaba recuperar.                 Finalmente hice esto y me ha funcionado.                                            `$(document).ready(inicio);`

```
function inicio(){

   // $("#btnfactura").click(valores);
   $('#tablaCliente tr').on('click', function(){
  var dato = $(this).find('td:first').html();
  $('#idCliente').val(dato);
});

}
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: no me he dado cuenta a la hora de poner el código                                    esta parte sobre ------// $("#btnfactura").click(valores);-------